# Can I check if an email has been secretly sent from my account?

Tags: outlook.com

I want to check if an email has been sent from my email account and then deleted from the sent folder.

I had a draft with some personal information on it and it disappeared. I wasn't sure if I had deleted it (I couldn't find it in the Delete folder, or any other folder) or if someone secretly sent it.

I'm using Hotmail by the way.

Comment: In my experience, it's more likely that an email account would get spoofed than logged into, used, and evidence deleted.  Only someone with Hotmail (Microsoft) would be able to tell you for sure if your account had sent anything whose evidence has been deleted.

Comment: If an email was sent from your account and the person who sent it deleted all traces of the email then what you want isn't possible.  What is easier to confirm is if somebody has access to your account.

Comment: Oh okay. Because I had a draft with some personal information on it and it disappeared. I was sure if I had deleted it (I couldn't find it in the Delete Folder, or any other folder) or someone secretly sent it.

Comment: @user2898051: That's important information that should be in your question. Comments are meant to be permanent. You can always [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Only the mail server admins who has access to the logs can see that. I do not think they are willing to dig through those for you as they are most likely massive, rather you would get a generic response if you contact them, telling you to change your password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned that someone has hacked your account, or could, you should follow the advice from Microsoft Support: [Help protect your account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/help-protect-account)

I did some testing and a deleted draft does indeed go to the *Deleted* folder. Deleted messages also seem to stay there until you explicitly empty the deleted folder. (The exception would seem to be for "child" accounts, where deleted messages are permanently deleted.)

So, if someone did have access to your account, the scenario you describe is possible and as [Christian](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82893/354) points out, only the administrators of Outlook.com could tell for sure what happened, and they're not likely to share that information. However, if someone did have access to your account, why would that be the only bit of shenanigans they did?

In any event, the advice on protecting your account is good practice whether you've been hacked or not.